# How we can edit footer in joomla to make it editable through Its editor(tinymce)

Tags: joomla1.5

Is it possible in joomla to make footer contents editable using its default editor or one we are using? if yes then how we can do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on making changes often, then you are better off just using the custom HTML module instead. You'd have to hack the core footer module to allow it to used editable parameters, so at that point you might as well just write a new module that does what you need it to do.

If you just want to make some changes to what the module displays and don't plan to edit often, then you can just use a template override.

Copy this file -

```
Joomla_folder/modules/mod_footer/tmpl/default.php
```

Put the copy here -

```
Joomla_folder/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/mod_footer/default.php
```

Edit the new file all you want.

Comment: thanks a lot sir,i want make changes often so as per your solution i tried it and i reached very near to solution but sir a problem arises there ,that in footer it only showing the title of new module which i created not the data which i want to show

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do what you want then. You can make a copy of mod_footer, then rename it as a new module. Then add parameters that allow for editing the contents. You can just use the custom HTML module since that allows for editing already. Or, you can use an article display module and create a category for footer messages. Set up the module to display only the most recent article, then add a new article every time you want to change the footer.

Comment: If you want help with the module you modified you should start a new question and post the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you open up your template's index.php file in an editor (e.g. Dreamweaver, notepad, etc...) and add this where you want your footer to display:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" />
```

That basically tells Joomla that if there is a module assigned to the "footer" position, to display it there.

Don't forget to add this to your templateDetails.xml:

```
<position>footer</position>
```

That adds the 'footer' position to the list of available module positions in Joomla.

Now when you log into the Joomla admin panel and go to your Module Manager, you can create a Custom HTML module and assign it to the 'footer' position. Whatever you put in that custom module will then display in your footer.

Best,

Cynthia